# Three points on a segment.

Tags: probability

Given a real segment of length $L$ and a real number $d$ such that $0 \leq d \leq L/2 $. Three points $x, y, z$ are chosen randomly on the segment. Find the probability that $|x-y| \geq d, |x-z| \geq d$ and $|z-y| \geq d$.

I solved for the case when only $x$ and $y$ are given using simple geometry, but I cannot draw a three-D image for this problem. Is there any way to solve it analytically?

Comment: Hints: The three random variables can occur in any of $6$ orders, so assume that $X < Y < Z$, find the probability and multiply by $6$. For this assumption, can you see why the desired event will not occur unless $d < Y < L-d$?  For a fixed value $y_0 \in (d,L-d)$, what is the conditional probability that the desired event occurs given that $Y =y_0$??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dilip Sarwate's comment gives the hint for the description of the region in the cube of sidelength $L$, and since the distribution is uniform in each variable the cube can be $[0,L]^3$ and the probability can be obtained by the volume of the success region divided by $L^3$. After arranging for $x \le y \le z$ we have $d \le y \le L-d$ and also $0 \le x \le y-d$ and $y+d \le z \le L$. This gives the following iterated triple integral for the volume of the success region (assuming $x \le y \le z$):
$$\int_d^{L-d} \int_0^{y-d} \int_{y+d}^L (1) \ dz\ dx\ dy.$$
Evaluating this, multiplying by $6$ for the different possible orders of $x,y,z$, and then dividing by $L^3$ to get the probability, I got $[(L-2d)/L]^3,$ which should be checked.

Comment: Right, by following Dilip Sarwate's comment I come up with the same result.